# How to create guest order programmatically for Guest User

Tags: magento2, programmatically, guest-checkout, create-order

I have followed [Create order programmatically in Magento 2](https://www.w3classes.info/create-order-programatically-in-magento-2/)

But it is saving the customer.

And When I skip customer set data and customer save then It's getting an error report like

"Please enter customer email".

Any thoughts ??

Comment: It clearly said that we need to set the customer for the guest order.

Comment: @khoa, So I should remove the customer save script only to make it work as guest checkout

Comment: Please refer https://www.siphor.com/programmatically-create-an-order-in-magento-2/ this link. I try this and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

The above answer is correct but the **standard** way is not to create the `Customer` in case of `Guest Checkout`.

```php
            $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart();

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
            $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId);

            $guest = true;
            if ($guest) {
                // Set Customer Data on Qoute, Do not create customer.
                $quote->setCustomerFirstname("Guest First Name");
                $quote->setCustomerLastname("Guest Last Name");
                $quote->setCustomerEmail("guest@123.com");
                $quote->setCustomerIsGuest(true);
            } else {
                // Create customer object and assign to qoute 
                /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer */
                $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
            }
```

Also, the best place to check the sample code for anything to do `programmatically` is in **Magento** Integration test cases present in `dev/tests/integration/testsuite/`.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3-develop/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Sales/_files

Comment: where do you get the customer-object from? Do you have to create is completely new?

Comment: @codiga that is `else` case, for `customer` order.

Answer (score 2):

You can check below blog for create order programmatically,
I have given full demo for create order in Magento 2,
Check link, [Create Order Programmatically](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2/)

You need to skip Customer create step, In above blog,
YOu need to replace,

```
if(!$customer->getId()){
            //For guest customer create new cusotmer
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderInfo['address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderInfo['address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderInfo['email'])
                    ->setPassword($orderInfo['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
```

with,

```
if(!$customer->getId()){
    //For guest customer create new cusotmer
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($orderInfo['address']['firstname'])
            ->setLastname($orderInfo['address']['lastname'])
            ->setEmail($orderInfo['email'])
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(1);
}
```